# problem in entering the Login and Password

Tags: nvidia

I have installed the Ubuntu 12.1 on VMWARE, but I am unable to login the system.
Its showing, that I can log in below but I can't enter the password (its not taking) but it is taking the username and it also telling to wait for the Graphical Environment to launch.
Kindly help to sort the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if you have tried upgrading system.

Try Following and let us know:

1. Press **CTRL+ALT+F1**, enter your login user, pass and run:
2. **sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME**
3. Then press **CTRL+ALT+F7** and try to log in

If it appears again, then

1. Goto Bash (CTRL+ALT+F1) then enter:
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
4. sudo reboot